# Facebook Open graph Meta tags errors

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

i'm having an issue with the new facebook meta tags the type of object is a song.

i took the example from here.
[here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/objects/builtin/)

```
<meta property="og:type" content="Song" />
<meta property="og:title" content="artist name - track name" />
<meta property="og:description" content="content" />
<meta property="og:image" content="artist image full url" />
<meta property="testappwebsite:song:url" content="the full track uri PAGE." />
<meta property="testappwebsite:song:type" content="audio/mp3" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="my app id" />
```

this is the errors i'm getting.
[image: facebook debug]

the wierd thing is that when i take the url and put it in my status. i'm getting the correct image, but i'm not getting the title that i added to the meta tag, instead i'm getting the document title.

is there any built in objects for song audio ?? because i cannot find it.

Answer (score 0):

Song is uppercase in your example - not sure if that has any bearing. See here:

http://ogp.me/ under Audio...

```
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
...
[REQUIRED TAGS]
<meta property="og:audio" content="http://example.com/amazing.mp3" />
<meta property="og:audio:title" content="Amazing Song" />
<meta property="og:audio:artist" content="Amazing Band" />
<meta property="og:audio:album" content="Amazing Album" />
<meta property="og:audio:type" content="application/mp3" />
...
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the `<meta>` tags into your `<head>`? Only the `<head>` is actually parsed.

Comment: Can you post a link to the actual page? Everything looks right from your post.